# AWS VPC - cannot ping from ec2 instance after changing route tables

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

## SOLVED

My inbound rule to the gateway was too restrictive only allowing ips from a specific subnet!
If this does help anyone else:

- VPC management > Route Tables > Routes > Destination should be open (say 0.0.0.0/0) and target should be the gateway.

---

It's been a long time since I was working with aws and I haven't been able to figure this out on my own.

Basically, my EC2 instance was able to ping google yesterday when I was logged in with ssh.
I had two rules inbound on the security group associated with the VPC:

```
IPv4    SSH TCP 22  my ipd

IPv4    All UDP 0 - 65535   my ip
```

When I changed the second rule to;

```
HTTPS   TCP 443 security group
```

I could use my ec2 instance as a proxy to access my opensearch instance on the same VPC  but, I could no longer ping google.

So, I added back the rule I replaced, and I still can't ping google.

I've confirmed that I have an internet gateway connected to the VPC.

I'm reading documentation and brushing up on my networking, but if someone does have an inkling right off the bat, I'd be very grateful.

Comment: Pinging from an instance to something _outside_ the instance involves the **Outbound** Security Group rules, not the Inbound rules. What is the configuration of the **Oubound Security Group**? Also, have you changed the NACLs from their default "Allow All" configuration?

Answer (score 3):

You should confirm that the subnet has a Route Table that points to the Internet Gateway.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I don't think this answer is unclear at all. great answer.